# How can I get the correct font in the correct place?

Tags: fonts, equations, symbols

Basically the problem which I am facing (which I don't know if its even possible to fix) is that whenever I want to write an equation in between some text lines (using $some math$) I get a font that does not correspond with the usual font I get when using $$some math$$. So, is there a way that I can either get the $$...$$ font using $...$ or use $$...$$ but not have it being placed in the middle of a new line. Sorry, for any confusion with the $ symbols, I hope my problem is understandable.

Comment: You need to provide the community with some way to replicate your setup. Can you provide us with a minimal example we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're experiencing? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Can you do that?

Comment: your  question is not understandable at all, and you provide no example. `$$` should not be used in latex (the syntax is `\[..\]`) but anyway it uses the same fonts as `$` just a different layout. That is your question is understandable but it describing a situation that does not happen by default in latex (and isn't easy to achieve at all), that you have different fonts set for inline and display math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font used for inline math (delimited by single dollar signs `$...$`) is typically different from the font used for display math (delimited by double dollar signs `$$...$$`). The inline math font is designed to better integrate with the surrounding text, while the display math font is meant to stand out more, as it's used for standalone equations.

However, if you want to maintain the display math font style throughout your document, you can use the `\display style` command within inline math mode. This command adjusts the size and style of the math expression to match display math. Here's how you can do it:

```
Some text $ \displaystyle some math $ more text.
```

This will render the math expression `some math` in the style of display math, but inline with the surrounding text.

Alternatively, if you want to use display math mode but prevent it from creating a new line, you can use the `samepage` environment from the `verbatim` package. Here's an example:

```
\begin{samepage}
$$
some math
$$
\end{samepage}
```

This will ensure that the display math remains on the same line with the surrounding text. However, note that using `$$...$$` for display math is considered outdated in LaTeX, and you should use `\[...\]` instead. So, the above example would be better written as:

```
\begin{samepage}
\[
some math
\]
\end{samepage}
```

Note. Load the `verbatim` package in your preamble to use the `samepage` environment. Hope this helps.